# Need help for running tkinter program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to GUI programming so I don't know why this is not working when I run this program it doesn't open tkinter window so help me out,this is only running speech recognition program

```
from tkinter import *
import speech_recognition as sr
a=1
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything: ")
    audio=r.listen(source)
    try:
        text=r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You Said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize your voice")

root=Tk()
root.geometry("2000x700")
root.title("GUI")
root.configure(bg="#696969")
```

Comment: Try adding a `root.mainloop()` statement to the very end.

Comment: Well, you need to call `mainloop()` in any `tkinter` application, so the statement is required. The only other reason I can think of is maybe because the window is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot you helped  me to get out of the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `root.mainloop()` at the very end of the script. This is one of the must-haves when you make a script using Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

add root.mainloop()
so this will work definitely